# Delay going back to Main Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In Main Activity I call the native Camera app. That is good. However after a shutter click the camera returns to the Main Activity. This would have been good if they picture was taken correctly. It looks like the Camera needs some time to save the picture and leaving the Camera app causes the picture to be dismissed.

Not sure what I need to do for the Camera to have enough time to save pictures!

```
   /** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}


public void openCamera(View view) {
    Log.i("Camera", "Inside openCamera");
    if ( checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext())) {
        if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                Intent intentCamera = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                startActivity(intentCamera);
            } else {
                Log.i("Camera", "Camera not permitted");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
            }
        } else {
            Intent intentCamera = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivity(intentCamera);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. To open camera use **startActivityForResult()** and you will get result in **onActivityResult** and base on result save the image in prefered location.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

and use this override method for getting image back...

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Sample Example follow this [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java)

> There are two types of intents:

`Explicit intents` specify which `application` will satisfy the `intent`, by supplying either the target app's package name or a fully-qualified component class name. You'll typically use an `explicit intent` to start a component in your own app, because you know the class name of the activity or service you want to start. For example, you might start a new `activity` within your app in response to a user action, or start a service to download a file in the background.

`Implicit intents` do not name a specific component, but instead declare a general action to perform, which allows a component from another app to handle it. For example, if you want to show the user a location on a map, you can use an implicit intent to request that another capable app show a specified location on a map. [More Info](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

**Note:- Image capturing is `Implicit intent`. You have to use `startActivityforResult()`. It will use your OS software app to capture image and return to you app.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this api for camera it is easy to use and can solve your issue.
https://github.com/kosalgeek/PhotoUtil

1. Download PhotoUtil.jar
2. Copy it and paste into your Android project at App > libs > right click on the jar file and choose Add as Library

**Take a Photo using Camera**

1. Add Permissions
   To use the camera, first you need to add permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

2. Dispatch a Camera and Save it to External Storage

To dispatch a camera and save a photo:

```
CameraPhoto cameraPhoto = new CameraPhoto(getApplicationContext());
Intent in = cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent();
startActivityForResult(in, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

To get the photo path

```
String photoPath = cameraPhoto.getPhotoPath(); //call it in onActivityResult() method
```

Snippet of code:

```
//declare them as global variables
CameraPhoto cameraPhoto;
final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1100;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  //initialize it inside onCreate()
  cameraPhoto = new CameraPhoto(getApplicationContext());
  
  //call it to open the camera
  startActivityForResult(cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(), CAMERA_REQUEST);
  cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
      if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
          String photoPath = cameraPhoto.getPhotoPath();
         try {
              Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
              imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //imageView is your ImageView
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
    }//end if resultCode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any `AsyncTask` calls in your Activity?

When I had this issue, I had other items in my Activity that were being run asynchronously, but upon which my UI depends. I called them using `myAsyncTask.execute(params)` instead of `myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params)`. Once I switched all my calls to the other pattern, this delay problem went away.

Basically, it's possible that your device is running something else in the main thread that's prioritized the AsyncTask's `doInBackground`, and your app then just gets stuck.